# Simple graphics library for tick-based simulation

Tags: c, graphics

I am creating a tick-based simulation in C, currently running on Mac OS X 10.8.4.
At the moment after each tick, I am printing out the entire world representing in ASCII to the terminal, using ANSI escape codes to move the cursor to the correct place.

I would like to transition to a graphical based representation of the world instead of using the terminal window. What would be a good library use? Also, what is the accepted way of performing multiple updates to the screen per second in this library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) since it is cross compatible with most OS and mature.

Also check these [examples](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-animation) for 2D animations in order to perform the screen updates you need.

Comment: +1 for SDL. I got started in SDL, it works wonders. Compatible with both C and C++ (Which was significant, as I slowly began preferring C as I used it), and gets the job done.

Comment: Hmm, seems I will have to rewrite the program so that SDL can have the main thread, as it won't work on any other thread. That's mildly annoying...